# Передать массив как аргумент функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, у которой среди аргументов есть массив, которую нужно выполнить несколько раз, как сделать так, чтобы значения массива передавались по очереди? forEach не подходит, хочу попробовать через цикл for сделать, но не знаю как по очереди передавать элементы массива.

```
function check(item){
    const balance = contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(item).call(function(err, result) {
        if (result>0){
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
      .then((count) => {
        let rawTransaction = {
          'from': address,
          'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
          'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(21000),
          'to': item,
          'value': web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("0.0002")),
          'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(count)
        }
        let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
        transaction.sign(key)
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
          .on('transactionHash', console.log)

      })
        }

    }
)}
```

Comment: А показать самую функцию вы не хотите? И почему for подходит, а forEach нет?

Comment: @Vearo добавил функцию, forEach не подходит из-за конфликтов в методах web3js, подойдет for или нет - я не знаю, просто хочу попробовать

Comment: Может кто-то подсказать?